# How do I make a 'properly formatted HTML link for an email address'?

Tags: python

I am in a computer science class. I was just given this assignment today. It was completely blank spare a docstring at the top.

```
'''
Write a function that returns a properly formatted HTML link for 
an email address.
Uber Geek Option:
Include code that checks to see if the email itself is properly formatted
Hacker Option:
Also include code that checks to see if the email is valid
'''
```

How do I begin this? I have tried sites such as WikiHow and RealPython. This may be an information error, but I am sure my teacher wrote what he meant in this assignment.

**EDIT:** I fixed most of the code, but I cannot get it to understand and replace the inputted email with the `emAdd` variable.

```
import re
def isvalidEmail(email):
    pattern = "^\S+@\S+\.\S+$"
    objs = re.search(pattern, email)
    try:
        if objs.string == email:
            return True
    except:
        return False

def emailAddress():
  emAdd = input("Enter your email address: ")
  if ('@' and '.') and ('.net' or '.com') not in emAdd:
    print("Enter a properly formatted email address.")
    emailAddress()
  else:
    cke = isvalidEmail(emAdd)
    if cke == True:
      print('<a href="mailto:'+emAdd+'?">')
    else:
      print("enter a valid email.")
      emailAddress()
      put_me_in_another_file = '<a href="mailto:'+emAdd+'?">'

emailAddress()

file = open("email.html","w")
   
# Adding input data to the HTML file
file.write("<html>\n<head>\n<title> \nYour Email in A Webpage \
           </title>\n</head> <body><h1>Welcome to <u>Your Email</u></h1>\
           \n<h2>A hyperlink to send emails to the inputted email should appear below.</h2><a href=mailto:emAdd?>\n</body></html>")
              
# Saving the data into the HTML file
file.close()
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be done in Python? Is it safe to assume that the function will take a user string as input for you to run format checks on, and if it passes all checks, simply return an anchor tag which contains the email? This might be a helpful link if that assumption is correct: https://www.wikihow.com/Create-an-Email-Link-in-HTML

Comment: Okay, assuming that your format check depends only on whether or not the user input contains an '@' and valid domain, this can be done by taking a user ```input()``` and storing it as a variable, running the variable through some if statements to see if the characters required for a valid email are present, and then using the ```+``` Python operator to modify the string so that it is contained within an html anchor tag. Attach your code if that gives you any trouble and we can go from there.

Comment: Before assigning this, didn't the teacher or textbook explain what an email link looks like? How can they give an assignment without teaching you how to solve it?

Comment: @Barmar Our teacher said we would go over it in class, we have not yet.

Comment: green_cube: Please don't post long sequences of code in comment — put them in your question if it's relevant to what you're asking (not just to a comment down here).

Comment: The `if ('@' and '.') and ('.net' or '.com') not in emAdd:` statement isn't doing what you think. The final value of `emAdd` needs to be put in the HTML string being written to the file. Unfortunately it's currently a local variable in the `emailAddress()` function which makes that impossible.